# How to Upload a file in BinaryFormat through ng-file-upload

Tags: java, angularjs

I am uploading a file to the rest server and it has to be converted into binary format but it always give me malformed exception.

My code on html page is:

```
 <input type="file" ngf-select="upload($file)">
```

Dependency in angular module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute',
                                 'app.filters',
                                 'app.services',
                                 'app.directives',
                                 'app.controllers',
                                 'ui.bootstrap',
                                 'ngCookies',
                                 'angularFileUpload',
                                 'ngFileUpload']);
```

Dependency In controller:

```
app.controller("elasticSearchController",['$scope','$rootScope','$http','Upload',function($scope,$rootScope,$http,Upload)
```

Code For uploading to Specific Url:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {

        var createIndexUrl='http://'+$rootScope.elasticSearch.url+':9200/'+$rootScope.elasticSearch.indexName+'/'+$rootScope.elasticSearch.typeName+'/'+$rootScope.elasticSearch.id+'?pretty='
        Upload.upload({
            url: createIndexUrl,
            data: {file: file}
        }).then(function (resp) {
            console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
        }, function (resp) {
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status + " "+resp.data);
        }, function (evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
        });
    };
```

Can anyone help me in this????